# Trying to Run Allegro 5 Program outside of Dev C++ results in error

Tags: c++, dll, dev-c++, allegro5

I have a program which uses Allegro 5.0.5. It is a basic shooting game that I made while following tutorials to learn how to use the library. I installed Allegro 5 in Dev C++ with a dev pack, and when I create a new project I select Allegro 5 application which automatically adds the following to the linker:

- -lallegro-5.0.5-monolith-mt
- -lshlwapi

The program compiles and runs fine from within Dev C++ but when I try and run the executable outside of the IDE, I get an error:

> The program can't start because allegro-5.05-monolith-mt.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Now my first thought was oh I need to include that dll file in the same folder as the executable, however I cannot find this file on my computer for the life of me. But it must be there if Dev C++ is using it.

I tried downloading the whole Allegro 5 folder to see if the file was in there but it was not.

After reading up on it I tried manually including other entries in the linker section which were allegedly needed to make a static version of the exe. However that did not work.

I also read that if you have a monolith version that it can compile as a static library if you have 
`#define ALLEGRO_STATICLINK` before any allegro include statements. That compiled as well but still did not fix the problem.

No one else seems to have this same issue so if anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It _is_ in the Allegro 5 folder—probably in the bin subdirectory.

Comment: @Sky I am an idiot, I found it right in the Dev C++ bin folder, not the Allegro 5 folder I downloaded. Thank you, including that worked like a charm